# CyanogenMod on Xperia Z1 compact: Amami or Yuga

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, ota-update, sony-xperia-z1, builds

I have in stalled CyanogenMod (CM) 12.1 on my Sony Xperia Z1 compact -- according to the CM website the name for that device is `amami`. The OS (Cyanogenmod version) that it runs, very much to my satisfaction, is 12.1-20150424-UNOFFICIAL-amami.

However, updates for `amami` that are downloaded, for installation in recovery mode, are refused because the ZIP installer (in recovery mode) says that my device needs a `yuga` update not an `amami`.

While the name `yuga` is reserved for Sony Xperia Z phones, which may be a generic class into which the Z1 compact also falls, I had expected that the `amami` updates, which are specifically for my device, would be a better fit.

Does anyone know how I can make the `amami` updates work on my `amami` phone with an `amami` ROM on it, instead of asking for `yuga`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an unofficial build/port of the rom. If You must use official N build of the CM rom you should first change to official CM rom.
 You can't simply jump from some xyz rom( that's what UNOFFICIAL rom is) to official CM Nightly(N) or stable (Milestone, M) rom.
 Also if you are happy with your current non-CM rom, you may continue using them. You have to get updates for it from the developer whose rom you are using. Check for updates at XDA-Dev or whatever other development site from where you got your rom.
 If you wipe and load official CM nightly for your 'amami' you will be able to receive and install updates from CM.

Comment: Makes sense I guess. But isn't it strange that it does first try to download the updates then in the 1st place?

Comment: It was an UNOFFICIAL ROM but iirc it was from the cyanogen web site.

Comment: @alle_meije Unofficial builds are by private donors and its their choice and responsibility whether they want to provide updates or not. That's why they are unofficial. CM puts many requirements and responsibilities on the shoulders of developers that may not be possible for the devs. Hence they use the CM source but don't want to go official.You can not download their rom from download.cyanogen.org.

Comment: Got it. For future peace of mind I'll just have to download + flash https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/126041/cm-12.1-20150915-NIGHTLY-amami.zip then. I must have downloaded the unofficial one when the official rom was not yet at v12. Thanks!

Comment: In the end it seems to be the TeamWin recovery manager app that I installed, which turned out only to accept `yuga` software. I could not even install the NIGHTLY from the Cyanogen site without flashing another recovery... Luckily that is solved, hope this post will help others.